# Data not being embedded in link

Tags: pug

I'm using Pug to create a link.

```
each evnt in evnts
            .row.list-group
                .col-xs-12.list-group-item

                    h4
                        a(href='/details/#{evnt._id}') #{evnt.name}
                        small &nbsp;
                    p #{evnt.dateTime}
                    p #{evnt._id}
```

The page renders correctly and the correct data shows up.

Let's assume that the #{evnt._id} is 1234.

When I click the link, I am redirected to /details/#{evnt._id} instead of /details/1234.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in Pug 2.0, syntax changed [like this](https://pugjs.org/api/migration-v2.html#attribute-interpolation)

Your code above should change to `a(href='/details/' + evnt._id)`